# variable is undefined with @import

Tags: less

Why is not working !?

color.less

```
@blue: #3A5795;
```

main.less

```
@import: 'color';

header {
    height: 35px;
    background: @blue;

    div#logo {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
NameError: variable @blue is undefined
```

How solve this problem ?

Comment: Your import statement appears to be incorrect. Should you not import the file?

Comment: The `@import` directive should be written without a colon: `@import "color";`

Answer (score 1):

The [proper syntax](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-importing) of the import statement is:

```
@import "color";
```

The statement with `:`, i.e.:

```
@import: "color";
```

defines a [variable](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-variables) named `import` instead (hence no error message for such typos).